How to View All Elements of a Pointer Array in Visual Studio 2022 Debugger
I have a class ArrayStack with private member T* arr. When I run the Local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio 2022, I can only see the entry at the beginning of the array. This makes sense since it's a pointer. Is there any way I can view all the contents of T* arr in Auto, Locals, or Watch? I tried to enter arr,30 into the watch window, but I get an error message saying arr,5 identifier "arr" is undefined. Note that at this point I have constructed and added values to the ArrayStack. I can open the memory debugger and see the contents, but this is not my goal. I'd like to see the contents in one of the Auto, Locals, or Watch windows. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Assume a class named ArrayStack, and an instance of said class is defined by ArrayStack<std::string> stack. You would then enter stack.arr, n into the Watch tab, where n is the number of elements you want to watch. n elements will be displayed, starting from stack.arr[0] to stack.arr[n-1].
